# Auto restart in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a command in MATLAB to automatically restart it (after shutting it down through 'quit') and run the same script with a different set of variables? 
For example, if simpleSum.m is a code:

```
a=1;
b=2;
abSum=a+b
quit
%some command here to restart matlab with (say) a=3 and b=5; 
%and then with a=5, b=-2; Then with a=7, b=-5 and so on
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this and not just [use a loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html)?

Comment: If the computation runs into several days, Matlab response becomes very weak due to its inherent memory issues (which, as the problem stands, is still unresolved).

Comment: This will require manually restarting. The objective is to quit and restart automatically with a new set of variables.

Comment: Maybe use a bash script or something similar to run the code?

Comment: @David: Can you give an example using simpleSum.m?

Comment: @user5461722 finish.m will be run after a call to `quit`. From mathworks: "quit displays a confirmation dialog box if the confirm that upon quitting preference is selected, and if confirmed or if the confirmation preference is not selected, terminates MATLAB after running finish.m, if finish.m exists. Call quit from the MATLAB command prompt". Further, I would recommend to use bash or similar. The commandline tool for Matlab was created for purposes like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a function instead of a script. Then you can pass the initial arguments to it easily:

```
function simpleSum(a, b)

% Use defaults when called without arguments
if nargin < 2
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
end
```

After the calculations are done and Matlab shall be restarted, you can do the following:

```
% Calculate 'a' and 'b' for the next iteration
cmd = sprintf('simpleSum(%d, %d)', a, b);  % Assemble function call
system(['matlab -r "' cmd '"&']);          % Start new Matlab instance
quit;                                      % Quit current session
```

Make sure that you add an '&' behind you Matlab call, so that it will be started in background. With "-r" you can specify a command which shall be executed when Matlab starts.

EDIT:
Here is the full file (simpleSum.m), that I tested:

```
function simpleSum(a, b)

% Use defaults when called without arguments
if nargin < 2
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
end

fprintf('Running simpleSum with a=%d and b=%d.\n', a, b);
pause(5);

c = a + b;   % Implement your code here
a = b;
b = c;

% Calculate 'a' and 'b' for the next iteration
cmd = sprintf('simpleSum(%d, %d)', a, b);  % Assemble function call
system(['matlab -r "' cmd '"&']);          % Start new Matlab instance
quit;                                      % Quit current session
```

Just use "simpleSum" on the Matlab Command Window to start it and it should repeatedly restart Matlab, until it is manually stopped with Ctrl+C.

Comment: It doesn't work in a loop:                                                                             for i=5:6
    cmd = sprintf('simpleSum(%d, %d)', i, 2); 
    system(['matlab -r "' cmd '"&']);          
    quit;         
end                                                                                                               It shuts down the initializing instance; then opens a new instance and runs for the first value (i=5) and stays there - nothing further happens.

Comment: You don't need a loop, as the function should open a new Matlab instance after it is being processed. It works like a recursion. See my edited post for a fully working example.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the new session of matlab first -- using system()
then you could call quit on the original session

Comment: MATLAB will wait for the `system()` command to finish, i.e. it waits until the new MATLAB session is closed. Before that, you can't `quit` the old session.